# Buying NFTs using Opensea SDK returns error message

Tags: nft, infura, opensea

So i'm using the opensea SDK and its [fulfillOrder](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js#buying-items) method, but its giving me the following error message: **The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available**

Yes, I'm using Infura and I know that is why this is happening, but how would I fix this? I know that I need to sign the transaction by myself, but how would I do that?

```
const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(USER_ADDRESS, "latest");
const tx = {
  from: USER_ADDRESS,
  to: ???,
  nonce,
  gas: 500000
};

web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY).then((signedTx) => {
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction, (error, hash) => {
      ...
    }
});
```

Is this approach correct? Which address should I use on "to" key?

Answer (score 0):

replace web3.providers to HDWalletProvider
https://www.cnblogs.com/chris2021/p/15894496.html